# Electric flux through Solid non-conducting sphere placed in uniform electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

What would be the electric flux through a Solid non-conducting sphere placed in uniform electric field and how?

Comment: This depends ...

Comment: Electric flux is meaningful for a surface like a spherical shell, not for a volume like a solid sphere.

Comment: Could you also tell me what exactly are closed surfaces?